# Magento 2.3 - Changed attribute media_gallery to scope "Store View", but want to revert it to "Global" error

Tags: attributes, sql, magento2.3.5, scope

We changed the scope of the attribute media_gallery to scope "Store View", but we want to revert it back to "Global", like the default setting.

But when we revert it, we get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'attribute_id' in 'where clause', query was: DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE (attribute_id = '90') AND (store_id IN(1))
```

How can we solve this?

Comment: did you tired reindexing??

Comment: @Chikku Thanks! Yes I did and tried it again, but that did not seem to work.

Comment: are you still getting the same error??

Comment: @Chikku Yes, the error remains the same in that case.